# Possible to join pdf-forms, fill and use passthrough in one command (PDFTK and PHP)?

Tags: php, pdftk

I use `pdftk` successfully to fill a pdfform in PHP with the following code:

```
passthru( '/usr/bin/pdftk /mallpdf/1.pdf fill_form '.$tmpfname.' output - ');
```

Now I have two pdfforms which I would like to join and then fill with data.

Tried the code below but no success, any thoughts? Or perhaps not possible?

```
passthru( '/usr/bin/pdftk /mallpdf/1.pdf /mallpdf/2.pdf cat fill_form '.$tmpfname.' output - flatten');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do two operations at once with a single call to pdftk. Fill each of the forms with a separate call, then merge them together with a third call.

Comment: Thanks @notautogenerated ! So I guess this would involve creating two tempfiles, fill them and then joining them?

Comment: Pretty much. The tempfiles would be the output of filling your original files, no need to create them beforehand.